# Is there a sistematic way to verify if some gauge group embedding is possible?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory

Consider the breaking pattern of the well known 331 models: $SU(3)_C\otimes SU(3)_L \otimes U(1)_X \to SU(3)_C\otimes SU(2)_L \otimes U(1)_Y$. In this case the subgroup $SU(2)_L \otimes U(1)_Y$ is embedded entirely into $SU(3)_L$.

How can I convince myself that this is possible and understand how it realizes?

Since it is straigthforward to 'generalize' the Pauli-matrices to Gell-Mann ones, we are left to deal with the $U(1)_Y$. I have tried to write it (for a specific representation content) as a diagonal generator of $SU(3)_L$ while respecting its normalization $\text{Tr}(T_iT_j)=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}$, but couldn't do it in a way that was multiplet independent.

How would one go ahead to do it? Is this something that can be systematically done?